# What could cause my Internet connection to drop on all of my devices when I plug my desktop into my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

My Internet connection will be working perfectly fine until I plug in my desktop running Windows 10. As soon as I plug in this PC, all devices lose Internet connection. They stay connected to the router, but no connection to the outside world...

What could be causing this?

I already made sure my desktop PC does not have a static IP. When I plug it in & run ipconfig /all, I get a self-assigned IP.

Comment: How do you know they stay connected to the router? Do you ping the router from these devices?

Comment: Also, `ipconfig` can't tell you if an address is static or not, even though you  know what the DHCP pool is and the address is from that pool then the client can still be configured with a static address, just using that particular address from the pool. That could cause address conflicts which might explain this.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd one.

I'm not sure how this would happen, but it could potentially be a MAC address conflict.  Have you checked to see if the LAN MAC address of the router is the same as the MAC address on the PC's network card?

If that doesn't help, could you provide us with the actual output of `ipconfig /all` from the PC and maybe some information about the router?  Brand, connection of other devices (wired or wireless?), how your modem is connected, what ports on the router are in use, etc.